# Replace short-tags in Joomla custom module

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

In one custom module I write something like below. This module placed in the top of the page.

```
(650) 123-1232
950 Queen Dr Suite 110, Daly City CA, 94015
```

In another custom module I write the same thing with few changes as below. This module placed in the bottom of the page.

```
950 Queen Dr Suite 110, Daly City CA, 94015
(650) 123-1232
```

The problem is I repeat the same content over and over again in custom modules and mistakes are probable to happen. So what I want to do is to use short tags as below.

```
{phone}
{address}
```

If I write a short tag as above in a custom modules I want them to replaced with some specific values all over the site. {phone} with (650) 123-1232 and {address} with 950 Queen Dr Suite 110, Daly City CA, 94015. Assume that values are already in the database.

Can this be achieved by write a Joomla plugin? Or what should I do? How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ReReplacer](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/replace/4336) - search and replace in your websites output. This gets the job done.

> ReReplacer is a Joomla! component and system plugin that enables you
>   to replace anything in your Joomla! site’s output with whatever you
>   want.
>
> ReReplacer will search the text (html) of your pages for your search
>   request and replace it with what you have told it to do. These
>   replacements are on the fly. That means they are not permanent. They
>   are done every time you request a web page in your site.
>
> This gives you great possibilities and power to manipulate the output
>   of your site.

Answer (score 1):

If plugins are executed for the module, you can use this for example

```
class plgContentShorttags extends JPlugin
{

    public function onContentPrepare($context, &$row, &$params, $page = 0)
    {
        // Don't run this plugin when the content is being indexed
        if ($context == 'com_finder.indexer') {
            return true;
        }

        if (JString::strpos($text, '{phone}') !== false) {
            $row->text = JString::str_ireplace('{phone}', '(650) 123-1232', $row->text);
        }

        if (JString::strpos($text, '{address}') !== false) {
            $row->text = JString::str_ireplace('{phone}', 'your address', $row->text);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

You just need to add plugin xml and install it. You can even add parameters to the plugin to set details via backend

Comment: this only handles the content section. not the whole site

Comment: @Dasun it works for content and modules if plugins are executed (i can't remember if it's by default like that, or they need to be triggered)

Comment: yeah, I saw, but I like writing code myself (if I have enough time) :-)